# Gradle: Module builds, but test fails to build

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have a Java/Gradle application.  For whatever reason, the module will build, but it's Tests won't.  It behaves as if it's not importing it's dependent modules.  For instance, I get errors like this:

```
C:\Users\blah\bah\FileServicesTest.java:14: error: package 
org.dia.repositories.interfaces does not exist
import org.dia.repositories.interfaces.DomainImageFileRepository;
```

However, the full application builds just fine when I do ".\gradlew build -x tests" at the top level Gradle project.

My subproject's *gradle.build* file references the projects that the tests claims are missing.

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":dia-db")
    compile project(":dia-datamodel")
    ....
```

I'm sorry about the dearth of information, I don't know how to add pertinent stuff and leave out irrelevant stuff since I don't know what's needed to solve the problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":dia-db")
    compile project(":dia-datamodel")

    testCompile project(":dia-db")
    testCompile project(":dia-datamodel")
```

The `compile` configuration will only modify the classpath for compile-time of the main source-code. Though there is indeed a dearth of info, this may explain what you are seeing. The `testCompile` configuration modifies the classpath for compile-time of the test code.

Answer (score 0):

Another way should be

```
sourceSets {
    test {
        compileClasspath = sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output + configurations.testRuntime
        runtimeClasspath = compileClasspath + output
    }
}
```

This code should allow test task to see the compile dependencies.